# Using "\n" in Garry's Mod draw.DrawText

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I want to make an admin-online list. I have the `v:Nick()` part down but I want to place a new line after it.

Example: (At the top right corner, the names are INSIDE OF EACH OTHER.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to go about it, I'm not a VGUI kind of guy, but I believe I have found a solution.
You could make a transparent panel with a DListView like this:

```
local DermaPanel = vgui.Create( "DFrame" )
DermaPanel:SetPos( 50,50 )

DermaPanel:SetSize( 500, 700 )
DermaPanel:SetTitle( "Admins online" )
DermaPanel:SetVisible( false )
DermaPanel:SetDraggable( false )
DermaPanel:ShowCloseButton( false )
DermaPanel:MakePopup()

local DermaListView = vgui.Create("DListView")
DermaListView:SetParent(DermaPanel)
DermaListView:SetPos(25, 50)
DermaListView:SetSize(450, 625)
DermaListView:SetMultiSelect(false)
DermaListView:AddColumn("Name") -- Add column
DermaListView:AddColumn("Rank")

for k,v in pairs(ply:GetUserGroup() == "admin" or "superadmin" or "owner") do
    DermaListView:AddLine(v:Nick(),v:GetUserGroup()) -- Add lines
end
```

Now all you have to do is a little ScrW() and ScrH() for re-sizing and you should be good to go! 
Also, I got this code from https://maurits.tv/data/garrysmod/wiki/wiki.garrysmod.com/indexe102.html so I could save time, I would really recommend checking it out if you have a chance!

Hope I could help, Birdboat